# Android App to switch to one handed keyboard on specific events

Tags: android, automation

There are apps in the play store than can do some phone configurations (volume, wifi etc) on specific nfc tags, wifi connections etc. I do not want to name specific apps so as to not advertise them.

The functionality I am looking for though is missing from those apps. I do not know if this is Lollipop specific or Sony specific but in the keyboard settings you can set it to one handed keyboard. I am looking for an app that can change this using NFC tag scanning (switch the input method when 1st NFC tag is scanned, and switch back when scanning 2nd tag)?

Comment: I originally posted this on the android enthusiasts site but people in the comments suggested it should be here

Comment: They were 100% correct with that: "Is there an app 4 X" is off-topic almost everywhere (and definitely on Android.SE) except for here, where it's the main topic of the site. But then, "how can I X with Tasker" is off-topic here, but fits Android.SE just fine ;) I've just linked the tag-wiki for additional details; this was by far no suggestion to "ask there" :)

Comment: There you go – enjoy! As I wrote, I'm using *Tasker* for years, and definitely can recommend it. Takes some learning, though – but nothing else comes close to its powers. Once you get used to it, you will certainly use it for more stuff :) Enjoy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried it myself, but this should be possible using **[Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm)** with the [Secure Settings](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.intangibleobject.securesettings.plugin) Plugin and, optionally, one of the [NFC Plugins](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/resources_tasker#group_892) available:

*Secure Settings* offers an "Input Method" action in its "System+" actions, to switch between input methods (which include keyboard apps). As for triggering that action, you can use any of *Tasker's* (or one of its plugins') conditions. *Tasker* itself has such a "NFC Status" action, but those mentioned NFC plugins might offer more flexibility.

*Tasker* is the most comprehensive automation solution for Android, combining "conditions" with "tasks" to "profiles". For your use-case, a "Switch Input Method" profile would consist of something like this:

- **Condition:** *State › Net › NFC Status* (configure accordingly)
- **Task:** *Actions › Plugin › Secure Settings*, and there *System+ › Input Method* (configure accordingly)

With that set up, scanning the configured NFC tag should toggle your input method.

Note that *Tasker* costs about USD 5 – but it's definitely worth every cent. I'm using *Tasker* for years, and don't want to do without anymore. There's a free 7-day-trial available on their homepage – and the dev even states himself you can easily extend those 7 days for another 7 days: Export your configuration, uninstall *Tasker*, re-install it, import your settings. Nothing for the long-run (you should definitely buy it then) – but good if you're still undecided.

For more details on *Tasker*, please take a look at

- the [tasker tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/tasker/info) at our sister-site of Android Enthusiasts
- my comprehensive list of [Tasker Resources](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/resources_tasker), listing all kind of plugins (grouped by topics) as well as tutorials and more